# How do I use combn for multiple regression (or an alternative)?

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, combn

I want to get regression coefficients and fit statistics from one dependent regressed on all combinations of two other independent factors.

**What I have** is data like this (Note the NA):

```
H<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:20,10,rep=TRUE))) 
H[2,3]<-NA
names(H)<-c("dep",letters[1:9])
```

So I want to regress "ind" on all these combinations using `lm`.

```
apply(combn(names(H)[2:9],2), MARGIN=2, FUN=paste, collapse="*")
```

"axb" "axc" "axd" "axe" "axf" "axg" ... etc.

One at a time, I could get what I want like:

```
ab<-data.frame(ind="a*b",cbind(data.frame(glance(lm(data=H,dep~a*b))),
t(data.frame(unlist((lm(data=H,dep~a*b)[1]))))
))
names(ab)[13:16]<-c("int","coef1","coef2","coefby")
ac<-data.frame(ind="a*c",cbind(data.frame(glance(lm(data=H,dep~a*c))),
                              t(data.frame(unlist((lm(data=H,dep~a*c)[1]))))
))
names(ac)[13:16]<-c("int","coef1","coef2","coefby")
rbind(ab,ac)
```

**What I want** is either all these coefficients and statistics, or at least the model coefficients and r.squared.

Someone [already showed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841678/r-how-to-perform-more-complex-calculations-from-a-combn-of-a-dataset) how to almost the exact same thing using combn. But when I tried a modification of this using `glance` instead of `coefs`

```
  fun <- function(x) glance(lm(dep~paste(x, collapse="*"), data=H))[[1]][1]
combn(names(H[2:10]), 2, fun)
```

I get an error. I thought maybe I needed to try "dep" repeated 36 times, one for each 2 factor combination, but that didn't do it.

```
     Error in model.frame.default(formula = dep ~ paste(x, collapse = "*"),  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'paste(x, collapse = "*")')
```

How do I get either one coefficient at a time or all of them, for all possible dep~x*y multiple regression combination (with "dep" always being my y dependent variable)? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure where you got that code, using `paste` inside a formula won't work and I don't see that being done anywhere on the page you link. You need to build the full formula as a string. Try something like `formula = as.formula(paste("dep ~", paste(x, collapse = "*")))`. And please show the code you are using to call that function it it still doesn't work. You may also be interested in the `leaps` package if you just want the "best" model, not every model.

Comment: That works, thanks! And I'll check out leaps too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer since apparently it worked:

I'm not sure where you got the code `dep~paste(x, collapse="*")`, using `paste` inside a formula won't work and I don't see that being done anywhere on the page you link. You need to build the full formula as a string. Try something like this:

```
formula = as.formula(paste("dep ~", paste(x, collapse = "*")))
```

Next time, please show the code you are using to call the function, not just the function itself.

You may also be interested in the `leaps` package if you just want the "best" model, not every model. ("Best" in quotes because this is a terrible way to do model selection in general, violating all sorts of statistical assumptions for multiple comparisons and the like. Check out the LASSO instead for a better way.)